# extracting from 7z archive failed when executed through command line

Tags: 7zip

I downloaded a 7z archive which needs a password to extract the contents of the archive. I used the command
        7z -e archive.7z

It failed with the following error:
error: Incorrect command line.

Can anyone tell me command to extract the file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to do way better than that. What command line did you type in? Have you checked the documentation/help file to see how you're supposed to use 7-Zip from the command line? This question is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: the command that I used  was 

7z -e archive.7z

yes, I did check the man page...Please let me if there anything more that I need to add..

Answer (score 7):

7z e archive.7z

Lose the dash.

Comment: @hue:  Look closely.  There's a difference between what you typed, `-e`, and what this answer says, `e`.  "Lose the dash" is a colloquial phrase that means "do not type the hyphen or dash character before typing e."

Answer (score 0):

setting password for extraction is similar to setting password for archiving
(password is PWD)

```
7z e -pPWD archive.zip
```